# How can I toggle protection and change the copyright in Audacity?

Tags: audacity, copyright, protection

I am creating the soundtrack for a video game, and I import the songs into audacity for editing. There seems to be no way to edit the copyright and protection in the metadata editor. I want to put my name and the year as the copyright, and turn protection off. These are all files created by me so what I am doing is not illegal, so I am not sure why my computer will not let me change it. I have tried external programs, and so far, nothing has worked. Is it possible to do this with audacity? If not, are there any programs that can do this with any file, and how is it done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What file format?

Comment: It is flac, but if it is possible, I would want to know a universal method that I can use with any file through audacity, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: I can change the format too, I would prefer lossless compression over no compression or lossy compression though.

Comment: @wwww copyright is more important, I think default permissions is the same as no restrictions.

Comment: I am unaware of any metadata fields in FLAC files that are not editable in File -> Edit Metadata.

Comment: @wwww , if you right click on a file, and select properties, there will be several tabs at the top. If you click on details, and scroll down, there is an uneditable field, labeled "copyright". It makes sense why editing the field is restricted, but it doesn't make sense if it can't be set in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong, it can be done in the metadata editor. add a field labeled "COPYRIGHT", it must be all caps.